# Definition of Levi-Civita connection map?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Does anyone know definition of Levi-Civita connection map that defined as $TTM\to TM$.

I would appreciate if you could give a good reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are thinking of is the **connector** for a given connection. For a vector bundle $E$, this is denoted by $K: TE \to E$ in [Natural Operations in Differential Geometry by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak.](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=YQXtCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=connector+vector+bundle&source=bl&ots=SJSOfCnDpC&sig=5ATu5ZGCMFJo2Ntnu5s9nwDY7vM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJlfrY6NXMAhVLJZQKHQm8BgoQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=connector%20vector%20bundle&f=false) This is an amazing textbook by the way; definitely my go-to reference for anything to do with differential geometry.